# Nginx as Web Proxy fails on https

Tags: nginx, proxy, https

I have been trying to configure nginx to act as a web proxy (like squid) to be able to modify headers. It is working with http, but https shows "Server not found". Also, I can access directly with the url and it downloads https resources, if I reload it fails to load https resources...... what am I doing wrong?

this is my nginx.conf:

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
types_hash_max_size 4096;
include       mime.types;
default_type  application/octet-stream;

sendfile        on;
keepalive_timeout  65;

gzip  on;

upstream @squid {
    server 127.0.0.1:3128;
}

server {
    listen 3120 ;

    ssl_certificate           /etc/nginx/certs/cert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key       /etc/nginx/certs/cert.key;

    ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    location / {
    resolver 8.8.8.8 192.168.1.254;
    #proxy_bind 127.0.0.1:3128;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_pass $scheme://$host$request_uri;

        #proxy_set_header Host $host;
        #proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        #proxy_set_header Request-URI $request_uri;

        proxy_redirect off;
            #proxy_pass http://$host$request_uri;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not enabled SSL in your `nginx` `server {}` block.

The line that needs changing:

`listen 3120 ;`

should instead be:

`listen 3120 ssl;`

This will enable SSL for that `nginx` `server {}` block, but if you have not noticed already, HTTP (non-SSL) will stop working on port 3120.

You may be able to set that `server {}` block to listen to both HTTP and HTTPS with the following:

```
listen 3120 ;
listen 3121 ssl;
```

but as you notice, it requires different ports.